# CSS issue in IE 9 - boxes collapsing left to right

Tags: html, css

I'll start by saying this is not my work, but I am trying to figure out how to fix it nonetheless... Here is the page in question:

http://www.getredwood.com/pro/

The three content areas at the bottom are the part in question. It looks fine when I look at it in Firefox or Chrome, but in IE 9, everything collapses left to right and the boxes actually overlap each other a bit. The CSS that's in there now looks a bit of a mess and I'm not sure where to begin. Would be most grateful for any ideas. Thanks!

I'm not sure whether I need to post the CSS code here or not...it should be visible through "Inspect Element" in FF, but if anyone can't see it, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

This lies within the compatibly that browsers have, what you will need to do is use javascript to determine which browser is in use then create a custom style for each, thus allowing you to make it work on any and all browsers

Here are some links that should help you out

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Best of luck to you

Comment: Note** i was able to replicate the issue you detailed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the links, will definitely check those out.

Answer (score 1):

it is very bad CSS and HTML coding...

try to reduce width of each 3 divs, should be solve your problem.

Comment: I agree with you, it's a complete mess. Re: your suggestion-- you mean that reducing the width for each one of the three divs might help this?

Comment: yes. if it is static page, i can write it again for you. is that static?

Comment: No, it's not static...let me take a crack at it. Thanks for the offer though!